# How are Python's C and C++ libraries cross platform?

Tags: python, c++, c

Many of Python's libraries, e.g. Pandas and Numpy, are actually C or C++ with Python wrappers round them. I have no experience with compiled languages and don't understand how these libraries are cross platform (i.e. run on Mac, Windows, Linux), since my understanding is that C and C++ need to be compiled for a specific operating system. How does this work?

Edits:
[How do you compile Python C/C++ extensions for different OS/versions of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721918/how-do-you-compile-python-c-c-extensions-for-different-os-versions-of-python) does not answer my question and therefore this is not a duplicate. This question is about understanding how it works, that question presumes this understanding and is about implementation.

Comment: you already answered the question. They need to be compiled for the target platform

Comment: They release builds for different platforms, you can see them all listed at e.g. https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files.

Comment: The same way Python itself is cross-platform. The Python interpreter is written in C. It's compiled for each platform seperately. On Windows, you end up with `python.exe`, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you compile Python C/C++ extensions for different OS/versions of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721918/how-do-you-compile-python-c-c-extensions-for-different-os-versions-of-python)

Comment: Python has both pure-Python modules plus those that have compiled extensions. These must be compiled per platform, and often per-machine to account for the various differences in libraries and bindings.

Comment: Thanks all. So the fact that I can simply do `pip install pandas` whether on Windows, Mac, Linux, is because the pandas package includes compiled binaries for all platforms, and when I `import pandas` Python will work out which binary it needs to use, based on my OS?

Comment: is your question maybe triggerd by thinking "how can it be cross-platform when it has to be recompiled" ? Thats just what it means for C++ and C code to be cross-platform, you can compile it (almost) everywehre.

Comment: If a compatible binary exists it can just grab it, otherwise it can build locally.

Comment: @idclev463035818 essentially yes, I only have a basic understanding of compiled languages so didn't know this or if there are any other details about how this is handled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, Python package using C/C++ compiled code require compilation on the target architecture for them to be cross-platform.

Under the hood, when you use `pip install pandas` for example, pip will look for the requested package on PyPI and, if available, it will install the `wheel` corresponding to your specific system. A wheel is a distribution mechanism that helps installation of python packages on specific python distribution and/or target architecture. Taking the example of pandas again, here is what an upgrade of pandas returned this morning:

```
applepie:~ applepie$ pip install pandas --upgrade
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.1.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.1 MB 7.2 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.15.4 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2017.2 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
    Found existing installation: pandas 1.1.2
    Uninstalling pandas-1.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.1.2
Successfully installed pandas-1.1.3
```

Note that the first step executed was to download a .whl file that matches my specific architecture (Mac OSX, x86_64). The file name has further information, for example it is pandas v 1.1.3 and is compatible with CPython 3.8. Running this command on a different machine would have yielded a different output.

You can view the list of available files for pip to look for directly on PyPI. Again, looking for [pandas on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files) shows that the most up-to-date wheel for Mac OSX on CPython 3.8 is named pandas-1.1.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl, which unsurprisingly is what `pip install pandas --upgrade` downloaded and installed.

I am no expert in python distribution, in fact I was only very recently introduced to python wheels, have never distributed python code and had to do [some reading prior to answering this question](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/#python-packaging-made-better-an-intro-to-python-wheels), however it is my understanding that Python packages with C/C++ components would first require compilation on each architecture and then to build a specific wheel for that combination of python version and computer architecture. If a compatible wheel is not found, installing a Python package with C/C++ may require compilation.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer I was looking for. Since you answered so precisely and unambiguously, I think this demonstrates the my question was of sufficient quality, on topic, and not a duplicate, so I've voted to reopen the question.